# Spring Security: How to force https with flag?

Tags: https, spring-security

With Spring security I configure the parts of my web app that need to be secured by https with `security:intercept-url` tag.

For example:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*secure*" requires-channel="https"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="http" />
```

This way all requests with "secure" in the file name or directories containing "secure" on the lowest level get https, the rest will get http.

Is there a way to use a flag to make Spring force https?
I could not get anything to work that takes stuff after the "?" of an url.

- `http://domain/abc?secure=true` => https
- `http://domain/abc => http`

Spring would then redirect transparently every request going to `http://domain/abc?secure=true` to `https://domain/abc?secure=true`.

Is there a way to achieve that?
The first pattern in the example achieves the result for a "secure" occuring before the "?", but I am looking for a solution/pattern to have a flag after the "?" only.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean that `http://domain/abc?secure=true` should redirect the user to `https://domain/abc`? Or do you mean that "any URL containing the request parameter `secure=true` must use HTTPS".

Comment: Yes, http://domain/abc?secure=true should redirect the user to https://domain/abc?secure=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make Spring consider fragments after the "?" in urls, the stripQueryStringFromUrls has to be set to false.

Here is a solutation I found in the [Spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100899-stripQueryStringFromUrls-missing-from-filter-security-metadata-source):
When this BeanPostProcessor is loaded, the property will be set.

```java
public class BeanPostProcessorImpl implements BeanPostProcessor
{
    final static private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(BeanPostProcessorImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {
        if (bean instanceof DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource)
        {
            log.info("********* Post-processing " + beanName);
            ((DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) bean).setStripQueryStringFromUrls(false);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This way pattern

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*?secure=true*" requires-channel="https"/>
```

finally works.

Comment: Rather than a PostProcessor you could just set the setStripQueryStringFromUrls(false) through the spring context. You wouldn't need to code this way.

Comment: I don't like it either. I did not find a way to set the property via the context. Creating bean definitions on DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource or FilterChainProxy created all sorts of horrible errors. Using a BeanPostProcessor was the only way I found to set a property to a bean spring creates.

Comment: Hmm, ok than, you could just extend the FilterChainProxy override just the getStripQueryStringFromUrls() to always return false and use your FilterChainProxy in the web.xml instead of the default one. I'm not sure if thats better though ...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you want to have a URL param which to tell spring to redirect you to an https channel.

So did you try:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*?secure*" requires-channel="https"/>
```

or if that doesn't work try an escaped '?' :

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*\?secure*" requires-channel="https"/>
```

---

I just had a look at the source for the `FilterChainProxy` (in 3.0.5.RELEASE) and it uses regular expressions to match the patterns. So you can have a look at:

`org.springframework.security.web.util.RegexUrlPathMatcher#pathMatchesUrl(Object compiledPath, String url)`

or

`org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy#getFilters(String url)`

to see exactly what pattern you need.

So even if spring currently doesn't support the '?' sign you can extend your own `UrlPathMatcher` and inject it into the `FilterChainProxy`.

Comment: When you looking at the mentioned getFilters-method, you see that everything behind "?" will get stripped anyway, no matter which filter you are using. Solutation is then to set stripQueryStringFromUrls to false. Thanks for the pointer.