# Java Spring how to force https ssl in webapplicationinitializer?

Tags: java, spring, https, spring-java-config

To force https in web.xml i was using this code snippet:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Is there an equivalent for this in Spring Java Config? I already figured out that i need a `ServletSecurityElement`. But how do i *connect* it to the rest?

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        context.register(PersistenceJPAConfig.class);

        FilterRegistration filter = container.addFilter("wicket.myproject", WicketFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("applicationClassName", WicketApplication.class.getName());
        filter.setInitParameter(WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

        HttpConstraintElement forceHttpsConstraint = new HttpConstraintElement(ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL, "");
        ServletSecurityElement securityElement = new ServletSecurityElement(forceHttpsConstraint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you will find similar question and answer with details explanation and code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441523/spring-security-how-to-force-https-with-flag Hope it will help.!!

Answer (score 3):

As John Thompson pointed out you were right there.  You just needed to add the security element you defined to the servlet.  On another note I noticed you had `""` as the roleNames parameter to the `HttpConstraintElement`.  This would actually cause everyone who didn't have the role `""` to be denied.  If you want this to work like normal (force https) don't give any roles.  In the end this worked for me:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);

        // Force HTTPS, and don't specify any roles for this constraint
        HttpConstraintElement forceHttpsConstraint = new HttpConstraintElement(ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL);
        ServletSecurityElement securityElement = new ServletSecurityElement(forceHttpsConstraint);

        // Add the security element to the servlet
        dispatcher.setServletSecurity(securityElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Those two little "" caused me so much time because I just got a 403 with nothing logged.

I have found that you can leave this parameter off entirely, rather than needing to pass new String[0].

Comment: This should be the accepted answer after removing the array parameter off entirely

Comment: Updated the answer removing the unnecessary parameter so that this is clearer to others. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get a handle on the servlet registration, then register the security element. Try something like this:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration 
     = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet());
registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
registration.setServletSecurity(securityElement); //your prev defined securityElement
```

Comment: Assuming that you aren't adding a custom Servlet, using  `ServletRegistration.Dynamic` to add the constraint is the only option I could find. If you are registering your own Servlet you could achieve the same via annotating your servlet: `@ServletSecurity(value = @HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL))`

Answer (score 1):

In the case if you use Spring Security 3.2 you could do this as follows.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https"/>
```

with http to https port mappings as well.

```
<security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="${port.mapping.http.port}"
                https="${port.mapping.https.port}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";    
@Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);

            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
                    new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);



             HttpConstraintElement forceHttpsConstraint = new HttpConstraintElement(TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL);
                ServletSecurityElement securityElement = new ServletSecurityElement(forceHttpsConstraint);
               dispatcher.setServletSecurity(securityElement);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, connect it to the rest? Looks like you should be set. Spring will auto-detect the configuration of the Java configured WebApplicationInitializer.

> Remember that WebApplicationInitializer implementations are detected
>   automatically -- so you are free to package them within your
>   application as you see fit.

See:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html#onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)

Comment: The first 8 lines in the `onStartup` method work. Now i added `HttpConstraintElement` i `ServletSecurityElement` objects and i think i have to add or set them to something to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

One way of do this is creating an HTTP filter inside your application:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("security.http")
public class ForceHTTPSFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String X_FORWARDED_PROTO_HEADER = "x-forwarded-proto";
    private boolean forceHttps = false;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(forceHttps && !request.getProtocol().toUpperCase().contains("HTTPS") && request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            Optional<String> protocol = Optional.ofNullable(((HttpServletRequest)request).getHeader(X_FORWARDED_PROTO_HEADER));
            if(!protocol.orElse("http").equals("https")){
                ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendError(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value(), "Please use HTTPS when submitting data to this server.");
            return;
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    public boolean isForceHttps() {
        return forceHttps;
    }

    public void setForceHttps(boolean forceHttps) {
        this.forceHttps = forceHttps;
    }
}
```

You can switch on/off the filter with a property by using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Moreover, you should inspect the header `x-forwarded-proto` because some proxies (like Heroku) remove the protocol from the URL and store it into this header.

And, of course here's a unit test of this filter:

```
public class ForceHTTPSFilterTest {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @InjectMocks
    private ForceHTTPSFilter filter;

    @Test
    public void testAcceptHTTPRequestWhenFlagIsDisabled() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        when(request.getProtocol()).thenReturn("HTTP/1.1");
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        FilterChain chain = mock(FilterChain.class);

        filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

        verify(chain, times(1)).doFilter(any(), any());
        verify(response, never()).sendError(eq(403), anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAcceptHTTPRequestWhenFlagIsEnableAndItHasForwardedProtoHeader() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        when(request.getProtocol()).thenReturn("HTTP/1.1");
        when(request.getHeader(ForceHTTPSFilter.X_FORWARDED_PROTO_HEADER)).thenReturn("https");
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        filter.setForceHttps(true);

        FilterChain chain = mock(FilterChain.class);

        filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

        verify(chain, times(1)).doFilter(any(), any());
        verify(response, never()).sendError(eq(403), anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAcceptHTTPSRequest() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        when(request.getProtocol()).thenReturn("HTTPS/1.1");
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        filter.setForceHttps(true);

        FilterChain chain = mock(FilterChain.class);

        filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

        verify(chain, times(1)).doFilter(any(), any());
        verify(response, never()).sendError(eq(403), anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testRejectHTTPRequestWhenFlagIsEnableAndItDoesntHaveForwardedProtoHeader() throws Exception{

        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        when(request.getProtocol()).thenReturn("HTTP/1.1");
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        filter.setForceHttps(true);

        FilterChain chain = mock(FilterChain.class);

        filter.doFilter(request, response, chain);

        verify(chain, never()).doFilter(any(), any());
        verify(response, times(1)).sendError(eq(403), anyString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer are good enough when using Spring Boot and External Tomcat. Here the correct configuration:

super() must be called and the existing dispatcher servlet must be taken from the existing container.

```
private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcherServlet";

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(container);

    // Get the existing dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = (ServletRegistration.Dynamic)
                        container.getServletRegistration(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME);

    // Force HTTPS, and don't specify any roles for this constraint
    HttpConstraintElement forceHttpsConstraint = 
         new HttpConstraintElement(ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL);
    ServletSecurityElement securityElement = 
         new ServletSecurityElement(forceHttpsConstraint);

    // Add the security element to the servlet
    dispatcher.setServletSecurity(securityElement);
}
```