# Spring boot+Spring Security one way SSL and two-way SSL endpoint for application

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a web application which has 5 REST APIs. All the APIs are HTTPS with SSL enabled.
This is connector tag in server.xml:

```xml
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="conf/jks/ketStore.jks" keystorePass="keystore" keystoreType="jks"
                truststoreFile="conf/jks/trustStore.jks" truststorePass="truststore" truststoreType="jks"
                clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Now I have to make only one of the APIs to be exposed over HTTPs with onw-way SSL. The other 4 APIs should be accessible only over HTTPS with 2-way SSL certificates.

What is the best way in approaching this problem with Spring boot and Spring 4 Security.

**Update**

I have progressed a bit on this. I have set `clientAuth="want"` and able to access the required API without presenting a certificate at client side. But I am not sure on the way to enforce 2-way for other APIs and write a custom filter to check SSL handshake. Is there a way to do this in Spring Security.

I have the below `MultiHttpSecurityConfig` class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
      .getLogger(MultiHttpSecurityConfig.class);


  @Configuration
  @Order(1)
  public static class SecureApiConfigurationAdapter extends
      WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private HttpAuthEntryPoint httpAuthEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private X509UserDetSer x509UserUserDetSer;

    protected void configure(
        final HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {
      LOG.debug("/SSL2waysecureAPI/");
      http.csrf().disable()
          .antMatcher("/SSL2waysecureAPI/**")

          .x509()
          .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?),")
          // .subjectPrincipalRegex(".*")
          .authenticationUserDetailsService(x509UserUserDetSer)
          .and().exceptionHandling()
          .authenticationEntryPoint(httpAuthEntryPoint)
          .and().sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
  }
```

The new connector tag in Tomcat is like below:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="conf/jks/ketStore.jks" keystorePass="keystore" keystoreType="jks"
                truststoreFile="conf/jks/trustStore.jks" truststorePass="truststore" truststoreType="jks"
                clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Comment: I think it's just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441523/spring-security-how-to-force-https-with-flag - requiring client auth in the connector should ensure that those endpoints that require http also require client auth

Comment: An easy way would be to have a front server (Apache, Nginx, Haproxy, etc.) taking care of the for you. Your Tomcat would be SSL-less, and your front server will handle SSL whenever needed.

Comment: When i try to call the /SSL2waysecureAPI/** without specifying client certificate, my controller is getting called. I think should be checking that using a filter or something to prevent accessing secure URL, without client certificate?

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that you didn't configure a role restriction and your request uses the anonymous user/role?

Comment: Manu, did you make it work?

Comment: @Manu, have you got it work? I am also interested in how to achieve this.

Comment: @RedCollarPanda Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @codeomnitrix , can you contact me by email kitcpp@gmail.com? I'm on vacation now and away from my PC.

Answer (score 2):

So if someone needs it - I did something like this in this way

First of all - server.xml  config file

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
            maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
            keystoreFile="conf/jks/ketStore.jks" keystorePass="keystore" keystoreType="jks"
            truststoreFile="conf/jks/trustStore.jks" truststorePass="truststore" truststoreType="jks"
            clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Then web.xml :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>securechat.filter.ServletFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

After that, any request to any endpoint will be hooked to this filter. Inside of it you can manually check any request.something like

```
@Component
public class ServletFilter implements Filter {

 public static final String X_CLACKS_OVERHEAD = "X-Clacks-Overhead";

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    X509Certificate[] certificates = (X509Certificate[]) req
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

    String servletPath = null;
    int port = -1;
    if (req instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        servletPath = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getServletPath();
        port =  ((HttpServletRequest)req).getServerPort();

        System.out.println("getServletPath = " +  ((HttpServletRequest)req).getServletPath() );
        System.out.println(" ((HttpServletRequest)req).getServerPort() = " +   ((HttpServletRequest)req).getServerPort());

    //Just in memory of....
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader(X_CLACKS_OVERHEAD, "GNU Terry Pratchett");


    //Here you can do checking for port and destination.
    if(port == 8080 && !servletPath.equals("/notSecureDest/something")
         //log error - we try to enter secured enpoint bu non-secured port and url
         return; // we decline request
    }else if(port == ??? && ???? ) {
        //if all checkings age good - we do
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.